# Rotations of 2D object in 3D space tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-3d

I would like to draw a fully connected graph on a plane, then adjust its inclination with the plane and link to every node in the network another role coming perpendicularly in the z-direction. Since now I came up with this, but the result is not satisfactory nor adjustable.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \foreach \x /\alph/\name in {0/a/one, 60/b/two, 120/c/three, 180/d/four, 240/e/five, 300/f/six}{
  \coordinate (\alph) at (\x:2cm);}

  \foreach \alpha in {a,b,c,d,e,f}%
  {%
  \foreach \alphb in {a,b,c,d,e}%
  {%
   \draw (\alpha) -- (\alphb);%
  }}
  \foreach \alph in {a,b,c,d,e,f}{%
  \node[circle, minimum width=1pt,draw] at(\alph) {};
  \draw[red](\alph) -- ($(\alph) + (-.1cm, -.2cm, 0)$) node[circle, minimum width=1pt,draw]{};}
  \end{scope}

 \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need something like this. You can adjust it to your needs playing with the angles in `\def\anglex{20}` and `\def\anglez{35}` options, which produce rotations around the axes.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zy{sqrt(2/3)}

% dimensions
\def\l{2}    % hexagon edge length
\def\h{3}    % height
\def\r{0.15} % node radius

% rotation angles
\def\anglex{20}
\def\anglez{35}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,%
                    x={({-\xx cm,-\xy cm})},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zy cm)},%
                    rotate around z=\anglez,rotate around x=\anglex]
\foreach\i in {1,...,6}
{
  \coordinate (A\i) at (60*\i-60:\l);
  \coordinate (B\i) at ($(A\i)+(0,0,\h)$);
  \draw       (A\i) circle (\r cm);
  \draw[red]  (B\i) circle (\r cm);
  \draw[red]  (A\i) -- (B\i);
}
\foreach\i in{1,...,5} 
{%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ii{\i+1}
  \foreach\j in {\ii,...,6}
  {%
    \draw (A\i) -- (A\j);
  }
}
\node at (0 cm,-2cm) {rotate around z=$\anglez$, rotate around x=$\anglex$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]